# How to replace office chair wheel?

Tags: repair

Hello all you happy people.

Kay, so I've got a star-based office chair, and one of the wheels has popped off. The attachment itself is still fixed to the chair, it's just the actual wheel discs that have snapped off.

I've tried whacking them back into place, and it works for a few days and then it comes back off.

1) Are there replacement office chair wheel thingies available in DIY shops?
2) If yes, do I need to be wary of size differences, etc? Or are they standard?
3) I assume I have to replace the attachment, how does one go about removing that? So far I've tried upwards pressure, clockwise and counter-clockwise spinning, cursing, and Cajun voodoo. No luck.

[image: It's like the home-office equivalent of the Russian Olympic rings.]
[image: I really should clean that floor...]
[image: My computer chair has sexy feet. Srsly.]

Comment: those wheels hubs are typically snapped in place and don't have any way to remove again without destroying something else,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about furniture repair; see http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/753/22 for more information

Comment: @ratchetfreak yeah I surmised that the entire attachment would have to be replaced.

Comment: @NiallC. ah, my bad. Didn't realize that this would be considered off-topic. Is there a more appropriate SE for this type of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an **Office Chair Replacement Caster kit**.

They're fairly standard on the swivel pin size. The caster (swiveling wheel assy) attaches where it swivels, use a broad, flat pry device to pop the old one out, push the swivel pin into the socket till it pops in place and you're back in business. The swivel pin has a kind of neck like the wheels do, but it's more rounded because it is made to be semi-removable for replacement. If the other four don't exactly match, replace them with the new ones.

Best match is to look for the manufacturer if you know the brand and check online for the kit.

Comment: All-round awesome answer. Should be able to get that easily enough around here, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have replaced those, but I had the fortune of working for a company that had spare seats with other broken casters, so when I pulled one off of one of those it did not matter.

The part that removes is not the part you have featured in your pictures. Those are the non removable axles. The point of separation is higher where the whole wheel assembly pivots. A strong direct pull down should separate it from the support arm that it pivots in.[image]

Comment: I find a screwdriver in that crack pops the thing off easily.  Spares are readily available on eBay.  Just measure the top shaft length and diameter.